# Using the recursive code, I want to return a set of 2 values (total files, folders)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples, subdirectory

I've written this program that does not use os.walk(), glob or fnmatch and that is intentional. It looks at the directory and all the subdirectories and files in that specified directory and returns how many files + folders are in there.

```
import os

def fcount(path):
    count = 0

    '''Folders'''
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        file = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            file_count = fcount(file)
            count += file_count + 1

    '''Files'''
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
            count += 1
    return count

path = 'F:\\'
print(fcount(path))
```

An example output I got was directory F gave me `700` for a total of 700 files and folders.

What I want to do now is use this code, with some modifications of course, to call `fcount('F:\\')` and return a set `(total files, folders)`.

An example of an output I want would be: `(700, 50)`. The `700` is `files + folders` and the `50` is just `folders`.

I am not sure on how to do this.

Comment: yes, use tuples. what's the problem?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Not sure how to implement a tuple in this set of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep two counts and return them as a tuple:

```
total_count = dir_count = 0, 0
# .. increment either as needed
return total_count, dir_count
```

You only need to loop over `os.listdir()` *once*; you already detect if something is a file or a directory so just differentiate in the one loop on that:

```
def fcount(path):
    total_count = dir_count = 0

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        file = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            recursive_total_count, recursive_dir_count = fcount(file)
            # count this directory in the total and the directory count too
            total_count += 1 + recursive_total_count
            dir_count += 1 + recursive_dir_count
        elif if os.path.isfile(file):
            total_count += 1
    return file_count, total_count

path = 'F:\\'
print(fcount(path))
```

The final `print()` then prints a tuple with the counts; you can always split those out:

```
total_count, dir_count = fcount(path)
print('Total:', total_count)
print('Directories:', dir_count)
```

Comment: I see it now. I was adding the counts to each loop and because I was doing that, it was impossible get a separate answer for each one. Now, all I need to do is understand this. Thank you!